# solr php configuration moodle , unable to detect php_solr dll in ext folder windows server

Tags: php, solr, moodle

Could you let me know the steps you did for installing solr on windows server 2012? I'm struggling to install it. I appreciate your help.

Below are the steps I did:

I have followed all the instructions but still couldn't install `php solr` on my `windows server 2012`.

I have installed `APACHE solr` and started it through command prompt and it started at port `8983` on my `localhost`, but not sure how to integrate with my `moodle`.

For `PHPsolr` are there any specific instructions to install, except to drag the specific compiled dll to the ext folder, or something else? I have checked the `PHP info` page and could not see the `solr` enabled. Please let me know. I'm stuck here.

Please consider as mine is a `WINDOWS server 2012 IIS7`

When I looked at the php error log it says

> PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.6\ext\php_Solr.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

When I tried to install from `php_solr-2.4.0-5.6-ts-vc11-x86`

> PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.6\ext\php_solr.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

When I go to `moodle manage global search` -- it says

> "No solr configuration found"

Comment: If the library doesn't load, that's usually caused by a mismatch in version - i.e. you have the 32 bit library but a 64 bit PHP - or the VC versions are different.

Comment: i tried both 32 and 64 bit php versions ..no luck but will try with the vc versions..will let you know ..thank you.

Comment: It may also be caused by php_solr.dll depending on another dll that's not present, such as curl or something similar. You can use Dependency Walker to see which dlls it expects to find.

Comment: it has curl and other dlls ..not sure about dependency walker will install and try..

Comment: i havent installed dependencies like PEAR and extension libxml (mentioned this under php.ini) do we have PEAR for windows?

Comment: installed the latest version of vc ..still no luck..looks like im missing something in configuration...let me know if you get any ideas